# Overriding or aliasing name of column in legacy database using Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm writing a Rails application against a legacy database. One of the tables in this legacy database has a column named `object_id`. Unfortunately `object_id` is also an attribute of every object in Ruby, so when ActiveRecord is trying to use these objects to formulate a query it is using the Ruby defined `object_id`, rather than the value that is in the database.

The legacy application is immense at well over a million lines of code, so simply changing the name of the column in the database would be an option of last resort.

Questions:
1. Is there any way to make ActiveRecord/Rails use an alias or synonym for this column?
2. Is there any way in Ruby to make the `object_id` method behave differently, depending on who is calling it?
3. Can I simply override the behavior of the object_id method in my model (I assume this is a terrible idea, but had to ask)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just kind of spitballing here, but you might try something like this:

```
class Legacy < ActiveRecord::Base
  #... all the other stuff

  #give yourself a way to access the DB version of object_id
  def oid
    attributes[:object_id]
  end
  def oid=(val)
    attributes[:object_id]=val
  end

  #restore ruby's default #object_id implementation
  def object_id
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This definitely helps fix part of the problem. The other part of the issue is that ActiveRecord needs to call the original column name when it is generating where clauses. For example, when I do `Object.find_by_oid(3)` it is going to generate `select * from object_table where oid = 3` which will cause an error because in the database the column is not actually called oid.

Comment: you won't be able to use dynamic finders for that field.  you can still use object_id in your scopes and :conditions clauses (or #where if you're on rails 3)

Comment: I can see one problem with this solution, namely that Rails will still generate the automatic accessor methods :object_id and :object_id= which will generate a warning like this: `warning: redefining `object_id' may cause serious problems` and is most certainly undesired. Is there a way to suppress the automatic method generation?

Answer (score 0):

Check out alias_attribute http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/06/20/alias-attribute/ I believe that it does what you are looking for.