# ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError - attribute? is defined by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got an existing db with some tables using the column name `attribute`. I simply cannot change this name as it would mean recompiling our whole application.

When trying to access the db, I end up with:

```
attribute? is defined by ActiveRecord
```

First up I tried using datamapper but I can't get on with it and am finding myself fixing things which shouldn't be broken - like nested attributes....

So, I've come back to ar and am using this to solve the issues:

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'radcheck'
  class << self
       def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
         return true if method_name == 'attribute?'
         return true if method_name == 'attribute_before_type_cast'
         return true if method_name == 'attribute='
         return true if method_name == 'attribute'
         return true if method_name == 'attribute_changed?'
         return true if method_name == 'attribute_change'
         return true if method_name == 'attribute_will_change!'
         return true if method_name == 'attribute_was'
         return true if method_name == 'attribute_column'
         return true if method_name == 'reset_attribute!'
         super
       end
   end
end
```

But that's messy and is messing me around when I actually try and access the table...

What are my other choices - are there any good ways around this little bugger?

Comment: Perhaps the solution on this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428987/how-can-i-use-activerecord-on-a-database-that-has-a-column-named-attribute-d

Comment: This one also can be help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348037/overriding-or-aliasing-name-of-column-in-legacy-database-using-rails-activerecor

Comment: I've tried this before: @radcheck = Radcheck.all(:select => 'attribute as attr'). But I still get an error :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer this myself because the above didn't fix totally.

Despite renaming the column in my controller:

```
 @radcheck = Radcheck.find(:all, :select => 'attribute AS attr')
```

I still couldn't actually use attribute.

In the end, I used [this excellent gem, safe_attributes,](https://github.com/bjones/safe_attributes) to do the trick. Now I can call with this:

```
<% @radcheck.each do |radcheck| %>
<%= radcheck.attr %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without worrying about ActiveRecord's reserved attributes, just add a gem in your gemfile and the gem will take care of name collisions automatically.

```
gem 'safe_attributes'
```

Enjoy RAILing..

Answer (score 3):

Without having to care about which attributes are reserved by ActiveRecord in Rails 3.0 just add

```
 gem 'safe_attributes'
```

to your Gemfile and the gem will try to take care of all colliding names automatically.