# Select Column Name As Not Working Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to change a column name as a way to sort a legacy db we have. I've already found a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143954/activerecorddangerousattributeerror-attribute-is-defined-by-activerecord) but am trying a different method.

I don't seem able to to use the AS statement. I've tried all these:

```
 @radcheck = Radcheck.find(:all, :select => 'attribute AS attr')
```

And:

```
  @radcheck = Radcheck.find_by_sql("select attribute AS attr from radcheck")
```

When I run the latter in the console, it seems to work ok but the output isn't correct:

```
irb(main):076:0* @radcheck = Radcheck.find_by_sql("select 'username, attribute AS attr' from radcheck")
  Radcheck Load (22.4ms)  select 'username, attribute AS attr' from radcheck
=> [#<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >, #<Radcheck >]
```

Is there something stupid I'm doing here?

Comment: No, that looks correct. What DB server are you using? What is the generated SQL as shown in the log?

Comment: Am on mysql. Have tried without the quotes as well. My output doesn't show anything - all I get is the attribute? is defined by ar. error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to access attributes of `@radcheck` elements? These attributes are not printed by `inspect` method (that is called by irb on the object when it tries to display it), but that doesn't mean they're not there. Try printing directly `@radcheck.first.attr` for example.

Comment: How about `Radcheck.all(:select => 'attribute as attr')` or `Radcheck.select('attriute as attr').all`? Btw, for printing results of custom selects it's much better to use `@radcheck.to_yaml` or `y @radcheck` shortcut for it.

Comment: these both work but only if I use the safe_attributes gem. It seems to be an issue with the column name attribute - you simply cannot seem to change it.